# Mautic Contact email reply not showing under contact history

Tags: mautic

Using Mautic 3.3.3 and trying to figure out why Mautic does not the email reply under the contact history. Searching the internet and posting to Mautic forums did not help.

Added debug print and it shows that Mautic is receiving the email from SES correctly, any idea why the reply email is not placed in the contact history log? is there other Mautic configurations needed to make it match received email to a contact?

php /path/to/mautic/bin/console mautic:email:fetch
1 email processed for {imap.mail…apps.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX with a criteria of UNSEEN

Comment: Generally Mautic logs the events in history and those events are related to either direct actions or campaign actions, are you using campaign event to track if contact responded or not ?

Comment: Thank you for the question.

 I tried both, 
1. send email from Mautic to contact, then reply from outside to Mautic, Mailbox.php getMail() print added code prints the contact reply subject and body ... etc. But not showing up in the contact history

2. Used campaign with test segment, ran cron manually, got email sent from the campaign, replied from outside to Mautic inbox, the campaign action to increment contact points, it doesn't and not showing in the history.

Not sure what to try next, this is important feature and holding up sales team from migrating and start using to Mautic

Comment: So basically none of the event is showing up in the history ?
did you check error logs of Mautic as well as apache/nginx any error there ? or perhaps any error notification in mautic notification area ? without error logging it will be difficult to find out what is wrong.

Comment: The contact history shows "Email sent" and "Email read" events correctly , but NOT the "Email Reply". There are no errors in the logs. Added print to Mailbox.php, getMail() prints the reply email correctly after email:fetch, but don't know what prevents Mautic from adding the reply to history or where to add print in code to debug further.

Comment: Okay, guess, I'll have to try this out before any further comments, never used response tracking before. Will try to get back to you asap

Comment: Just checking if you had time to look into this

Comment: HI, I am sorry been super busy lately, is it still not resolved ? If not i guess i'll get time next month only.

Comment: No, it is not resolved, we don't know where to look in the code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess the question is, in code base v3.3.3, should it add received email reply to contact history? 
We can see that Mautic receives the email reply (Mailbox.php getMail()) after fetch command runs, can't tell what the code does with it after that. Searched for a design or code documentation and can't find any.

Comment: upgraded to 4.0.0, contact email reply still not showing in contact profile, what we need to do to get it work?

Comment: can you please use my website to reach out to me tutorialsjoint.com and we can take conversation further through mail and call to try and debug together.

Comment: Figured out the email replied, now contact history shows "Email Replied", but it doesn't give you the email reply to view like "Email Sent". May be it is not implemented yet, will put feature request. Thanks.

Comment: glad you figured it.